# Changing PATH Environment Variable for all Users. (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, environment-variables, path, ubuntu-8.04

I recently compiled Ruby Enterprise Edition (REE) on an Ubuntu 8.04 server.

I would like to update my PATH to ensure this new version of Ruby (found in `/opt/ruby_ee/bin`) supersedes the older version in `/usr/local/bin`. (I still want the old version around, though.)

*I would like these PATH changes to affect all users and crontabs.*

**Attempted Solution #1:**

The REE documentation recommends placing the REE bin folder at the beginning of the global PATH in `/etc/environment`. I altered the PATH in this file to read:

```
PATH="/opt/ruby_ee/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

This did not affect my `PATH` at all.

**Attempted Solution #2:**

Next I followed [these instructions](http://woss.name/2010/03/15/updating-the-path-everywhere-on-ubuntu-09-10/) and updated the PATH setting in `/etc/login.defs` and `/etc/crontab`. (I did not change `/etc/sudoers`.)

This didn't affect my `PATH` either, even after logging out and rebooting the server.

**Other information:**

- I seem to be having the same [problem described here](https://superuser.com/questions/142345/etc-environment-not-being-read-into-path-variable).
- I'm testing using the commands "`echo $PATH`" and "`ruby -v`".
- My shell is bash. My `.bashrc` doesn't override my PATH.
- Yes, I have heard of the Ruby Version Manager project. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried altering the default bashrc?  This should be located in either /etc/bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc (I think it's the second one in Ubuntu). Then in your home directory, make sure your .bash_profile includes:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi
```

This will make sure that the variables defined system-wide are read into the user's shell.  This if-statement should be included by default in the .bash_profile created when you `adduser` (I know it is in RHEL).

Comment: Adding `PATH="/opt/ruby_ee/bin:$PATH"` to `/etc/bash.bashrc` did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, `/etc/environment` isn't loaded until you open a new shell / log in again.
Did you log-off and on?

Comment: I'm ssh'ing into the server. I have logged in and out a few times. I even restarted the server. :)

Comment: `/etc/environment isn't read by the shell.

Comment: According to the Ubuntu help pages, it is. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: This was the confusing part for me, the fact that the Ubuntu docs claim that /etc/environment is a root PATH source. Also, the fix I link to in the second attempted solution shows that changing this file works for some Ubuntu users.